# Build error with a Hello World C program with a default CDT plugin installation in Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed the CDT plugin for Eclipse on my Ubuntu machine. I made a new Hello World ANSI C Project and put the code for a basic C program inside the source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I go to build the program, I get the error that "Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'CS47 HW2'.
Illegal character in path at index 4: CS47 HW2"

Furthermore, 2 errors occur when I go to build the program in the Problems window, along with 85 warnings. The two errors are:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
./src/CS47 HW2.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC    CS47 HW2            C/C++ Problem

and

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [libCS47 HW2] Error 1 CS47 HW2            C/C++ Problem

Comment: It looks like Eclipse does not allow space in the project name, change the project name to something like 'CS47_HW2' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First comment nailed it. For some reason Eclipse would allow a space in the project name with the CDT plugin.